# list index out of range on my while and I don't know what to do

Tags: python, while-loop

I've been trying to make a program with 2 lists. First list is Questions, that there is stored data      that I have to compare them with the user input. If the user input is exactly the same with an item from the list (Questions), then print the other data from the second list.
For example:

```
Questions=["hello","yellow","horse"]
Ans=["world","I pref red","I pref dog"]

# now if input of user is something from the Questions list, it will print # from Ans
# if input --> yellow
# then --> print(Ans[1])
```

The code that I wrote is this :

```
x = len(Questions)
leng = int(x / 2)


quest = str(input('Which your question: '))

while(quest!='@'):
    counter = 0
    if(quest == Questions[counter]):
        print(Ans[counter])
    else:
        counter+=1
        while(quest != Questions[counter] and counter<x):
            counter+=1

    print(Ans[counter])
    quest = str(input('Which your question: '))
```

For a reason I am taking this error: list index out of range line 244, in 
    while(quest != Questions[counter] and counter

Answer (score 1):

If the question isn't in your list, it will traverse the list and then throw an index out of range when it tries to access an element of the list that doesn't exist.

Could you use a dictionary for this?

```py
questions = {
    "hello": "world",
    "yellow": "I pref red",
    "horse": "I pref dog"
}

quest = str(input('Which your question: '))

while (quest != '@'):
    if quest in questions:
      print(questions[quest])
    else:
      print("invalid input")
    quest = str(input('Which your question: '))
```

Would recommend reading through some documentation on dictionaries:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

https://realpython.com/python-dicts/

Answer (score 0):

If the answer is not on the list, then `counter==x` (which refers to a non-existent element).

In general, parallel lists should nit be used as they are hard to manipulate and maintain. A better solution is to use a dictionary:

```
qAndA = {"hello" : "world", "yellow" : "I pref red", 
         "horse": "I pref dog"}
if quest in qAndA:
    print(qAndA[quest]) # Otherwise, repeat
```

Comment: and with qAndA[quest] I am printing only the yellow or I pref dog etc ?

Comment: Why don't you try?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a dictionary structure:

```py
questions = {
    "hello": "world",
    "yellow": "I pref red",
    "horse": "I pref dog"
}

quest = ""

while quest != '@':
    quest = str(input('Which your question: '))
    answer = questions.get(quest, "I have no answer")
    print(answer)
```